# How to get value of Selected items of Select2 when submitted?

Tags: laravel-5, jquery-select2

What options I should set to get the value of the options when I submit the form?

I am using Select2. I have given the code I have to setup the select2, controller that returns the data, the html code that renders the element.

Html Code to add the select2 element:

```
<div class="form-group row"><label class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">Keyword</label>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
      <select class="form-control w-50" name="keywords[]"     id="keyword" multiple="multiple">
     </select>
   <span class="form-text m-b-none">One or multiple keywords</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Datasource is an Ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#keyword').select2({
        tags: true,
        tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],

   placeholder: 'Select keyword',
    ajax: {
      url: 'https://rankypro.dev/app/json/keywords',
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 250,
      processResults: function (data) {
        return {
          results:  $.map(data, function (item) {
                return {
                    text: item.name,
                    id: item.id
                }
            })
        };
      },
      cache: true
    }
  });
```

Controller:

```
public function getKeywords(Request $request){

    $search = $request->search;

    if($search == ''){
        $keywords = Term::orderby('name','asc')
                    ->select('id','name')
                    ->where('taxonomy','keyword')
                    ->limit(5)
                    ->get();
     }else{
        $keywords = Term::orderby('name','asc')->select('id','name')
                        ->where('taxonomy','keyword')
                        ->where('name', 'like', '%' .$search . '%')
                        ->limit(5)
                        ->get();
     }

   $results = array();
        foreach($keywords as $keyword){
            $results[] = array(
                "id"=>$keyword->id,
                "text"=>$keyword->name
            );
        }
   echo json_encode($results);
   exit();
}
```

I am testing with:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    dd($request->keywords);
}
```

I get the following:

```
array:2 [
     0 => "Tools"
     1 => "SEO"
  ]
```

I actually need ids of the keywords. Would you please give some hints how can I get that.

Answer (score 0):

I think their is some issue in rendering data. Try to replace

```
processResults: function (data) {
        return {
          results:  $.map(data, function (item) {
                return {
                    text: item.name,
                    id: item.id
                }
            })
        };
      },
```

With

```
processResults: function (data) {

      return {
        results: data.item
      };
    },
```

select2 automatically render id and name.

Comment: Tried. Not working. Get error.  Query.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefine

Comment: Can you show me the demo?  then only I can find out the proper solutions.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: I have fixed it. I needed to transform the data into required format before adding it to the Select2.  https://snipboard.io/RboOym.jpg